# I can not upgrade from Magento 2.2.5 to Magento 2.2.6

Tags: magento2, magento-upgrade

When upgrading from Magento 2.2.5  to Magento 2.2.6, it is output as follows.

```
$ cd /var/www/html/magento_project
$ php bin/magento maintenance:enable
$ composer update
$ composer require magento/product-community-edition 2.2.6 --no-update

./composer.json has been updated
```

And I can not upgrade.

Please tell me what to do.

Comment: Try this commands : **git checkout composer.json** ,**composer clearcache**, **composer require magento/product-community-edition 2.2.6 --no-update**,
**composer update**

Comment: Have you done setup upgrade?

Comment: We thank you for your cooperation. I resolved it by running the command as instructed by Magento 2 Devloper. Thank you.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Open your root composer.Json and replace whole code with below.

```
{
    "name": "magento/project-community-edition",
    "description": "eCommerce Platform for Growth (Community Edition)",
    "type": "project",
    "version": "2.2.6",
    "license": [
        "OSL-3.0",
        "AFL-3.0"
    ],
    "require": {
        "magento/product-community-edition": "2.2.6",
        "composer/composer": "@alpha"
    },
    "require-dev": {
        "phpunit/phpunit": "~6.2.0",
        "squizlabs/php_codesniffer": "3.2.2",
        "phpmd/phpmd": "@stable",
        "pdepend/pdepend": "2.5.2",
        "friendsofphp/php-cs-fixer": "~2.2.1",
        "lusitanian/oauth": "~0.8.10",
        "sebastian/phpcpd": "2.0.4"
    },
    "autoload": {
        "psr-4": {
            "Magento\\Framework\\": "lib/internal/Magento/Framework/",
            "Magento\\Setup\\": "setup/src/Magento/Setup/",
            "Magento\\": "app/code/Magento/"
        },
        "psr-0": {
            "": [
                "app/code/",
                "generated/code/"
            ]
        },
        "files": [
            "app/etc/NonComposerComponentRegistration.php"
        ],
        "exclude-from-classmap": [
            "**/dev/**",
            "**/update/**",
            "**/Test/**"
        ]
    },
    "autoload-dev": {
        "psr-4": {
            "Magento\\Sniffs\\": "dev/tests/static/framework/Magento/Sniffs/",
            "Magento\\Tools\\": "dev/tools/Magento/Tools/",
            "Magento\\Tools\\Sanity\\": "dev/build/publication/sanity/Magento/Tools/Sanity/",
            "Magento\\TestFramework\\Inspection\\": "dev/tests/static/framework/Magento/TestFramework/Inspection/",
            "Magento\\TestFramework\\Utility\\": "dev/tests/static/framework/Magento/TestFramework/Utility/"
        }
    },
    "minimum-stability": "stable",
    "repositories": [
        {
            "type": "composer",
            "url": "https://repo.magento.com/"
        }
    ],
    "extra": {
        "magento-force": "override"
    }
}
```

After update composer.json need to run below command.

```
 composer update
 php bin/magento s:up
 php bin/magento s:s:d -f
 php bin/magento c:c
 rm -rf var/cache/* generated/*
```

**Note:: If you have uploaded any extension using composer command then you need to add lib in a composer.json**

Comment: thank you for your cooperation. The command was executed according to the instructions of Magento 2 Devloper. I think that it succeeded. If another problem occurs, add comments.

Comment: ok if everything fine you can upvote this answer

Comment: Third party extensions are gone after updating. Is there a workaround for such cases?

Comment: Yes, You need to just copy in a composer.json file. check my note

Comment: like - "sebastian/phpcpd": "2.0.4" ,  you need to copy old composer.json to new

Comment: To sum up the story, you can copy the difference of the old composer.json file to the new composer.json file.It has already been updated to 2.2.6. Would not it be okay to run it again?

Comment: I have successfully updated the update with your cooperation and confirmed that the website is doing the correct operation. Thank you very much.

Comment: you're welcome...

Answer (score 0):

Run the commands in that order

```
php bin/magento maintenance:enable
composer require magento/product-community-edition 2.2.6 --no-update
composer update
```

Comment: The situation does not change. './composer.json has been updated' is output.

Answer (score 0):

```
composer require magento/product-community-edition 2.2.6 --no-update
composer update
rm -rf var/di var/generation
php bin/magento cache:clean
php bin/magento cache:flush
php bin/magento setup:upgrade
php bin/magento setup:di:compile
php bin/magento indexer:reindex
```